# Hibernate JpaRepository Lock Table in a native query

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm using spring boot with hibernate 5 and the JpaRepository interface for my Dao.

I have a situation where external services can ask for a token to do some work, and then return the token when they are done. There is a limit on how many tokens I can give out.

My current solution is to count the number of existing 'IN_PROGRESS' records in the table and then insert another 'IN_PROGRESS' or 'DECLINED' row into my table based on the result. I then return that record back. Here is what that looks like

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "" +
        "INSERT INTO migration_records (id, client_id, status) " +
        "SELECT ?1, ?2," +
        "  CASE WHEN (SELECT count(*) " +
        "             FROM (SELECT id FROM migration_records " +
        "                   WHERE status = 'IN_PROGRESS' FOR UPDATE) recs) >= " +
        "            CAST((SELECT VALUE " +
        "                  FROM settings " +
        "                  WHERE id = 'POOL_SIZE') AS NUMERIC) " +
        "  THEN 'DECLINED' " +
        "  ELSE 'IN_PROGRESS' END "
)
@Modifying
int createMigration(UUID migrationId, String clientId);
```

I thought that the `FOR UPDATE` part of the query would help but I still get many race conditions.

I tried adding this`'@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.REPEATABLE_READ)` annotation but then I get a `java.lang.IllegalStateException: EntityManager is closed` error instead.

Any idea how to do this? I will also accept alternate ways to solve this problem